# Lambda expression on ArrayList

Tags: java, arraylist, lambda, java-8

I have problem with `ArrayList` and lambda expression. I have code:

```
MyList<Integer> list = MyList.make(1,2,8, 10, 11, 30, 3, 4);
list.letsGo( (e, i) -> list.set(i, e*2));

e - element
i - index
```

How should I implement for every lambda expression with `(e, i)`?

```
void letsGo(Function function)
```

Could you help me with implementation? How to get lambda expression from argument? I know about `apply` method but I don't know how to use it there..

Comment: First of all, if you know about the `apply` method, why not just call it?  Secondly, a `Function` only takes one argument, but your lambda takes two.  They are thus not compatible.  And without knowing the signature of `set`, I cannot suggest an alternative.

Comment: what should the `letsGo` method do?

Comment: execute lambda, In that expression, every element whould by replace by element * 2

Comment: `List<Integer> list=Arrays.asList(1, 2, 8, 10, 11, 30, 3, 4); list.replaceAll(e->e*2);` What’s the benefit of your `MyList` class?

Answer (score 0):

If you're trying to implement a `letsGo()` method that can use a lambda expression with two inputs, then I think you want the signature to be like the following (assuming `MyList` is parameterised by type `T`):

```
void letsGo(BiConsumer<? super T, ? super Integer> consumer)
```

I'm not convinced this is the best way to design your class (I'd have expected a method that takes a function, and updates all the values in-situ, like [`Stream.map()`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/stream/Stream.html#map-java.util.function.Function-) does, rather than needing to call `list.set()` in your lambda)

Obviously how you implement this method depends on how `MyList` is implemented, but an example could be the following:

```
public class MyList<T> {
    private Map<Integer, T> values = new HashMap<>();

    public void set(int i, T value) {
        values.put(i, value);
    }

    public void letsGo(BiConsumer<? super T, ? super Integer> consumer) {
        System.out.println("Let's Go");
        values.entrySet().forEach(e -> consumer.accept(e.getValue(), e.getKey()));
    }

    @Override
    public String toString() {
        return values.toString();
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        MyList<Integer> myList = new MyList<>();
        myList.set(0, 0);
        myList.set(1, 1);
        myList.set(2, 2);

        System.out.println(myList.toString());
        myList.letsGo((e, i) -> myList.set(i, e * 2));
        System.out.println(myList.toString());

        // Output:
        // {0=0, 1=1, 2=2}
        // Let's Go
        // {0=0, 1=2, 2=4}
    }
}
```

Comment: `BiConsumer<? super T, ? super Integer>` might be a little improvement.

Comment: Most collections, including `HashMap`, don’t like to be manipulated while being iterated. It might work in this specific case, but still is not the right way to achieve it. After all, why performing hash lookups for every element, when there is a ready made method like `replaceAll` that does the job without additional lookup. Besides, why use a `Map<Integer, T>` instead of a `List<T>`?

Comment: If you stick to the `Map` approach, you can replace `values.entrySet().forEach(e -> consumer.accept(e.getValue(), e.getKey()));` with the much simpler `values.forEach(consumer);`